# momentjs: Get invalid date when trying to get current date with moment()

Tags: coffeescript, momentjs

Hi Im using firefox and CoffeeScript in an app, I want to get current date with momentjs using default method `moment()` however when I debug the code I see`invalid Date`, it is very weird, this is my code:

```
questionStarts = 
    started_at: moment()
    running: true
```

Then later in my code I create another object and add the property

```
answer = {}
answer.started_at = questionStarts.started_at
```

But when I check `answer.started_at` I get back `Invalid date` any idea?

Comment: What version of moment are you using... try updating - could be a bug in specific version.

Comment: I have last version Im using meteor.js package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moment has an alternate constructor for strange dates. Since I can't see the value of `answer.started_at` in your code, I can only guess about how to solve your problem.

Consider for example some strange date format like `08.16.2015 00:00:00`. Trying to construct a moment object from it will give the same error you have, `Invalid date`. That's what happens if you tried constructing my example like this:

```
//this doesn't work, throws Invalid date message
var ex = moment('08.16.2015 00:00:00');
```

So, to fix my problem, I give another constructor that informs Moment of the strange date format.

```
//this does work, however
var ex = moment('08.16.2015 00:00:00', 'MM.DD.YYYY hh:mm:ss');
```

Now, I can use `ex` as a typical moment object taking advantage of moment's other methods such as `format()` `diff()` and `isBetween()`.

Comment: yes I solved it like a week ago and was what you are saying. Thanks anyways =)

Comment: Could you help solve this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61967235/react-native-moment-not-working-for-specific-time-value-without-debug-mode