# React native : moment not working for specific time value without debug mode

Tags: react-native, momentjs

I have below code where I format the time value to be date format.

```
 const arrivalDateTime = moment(
   `${todaysDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD")} ${arrivalTime}:00:00`,
 ).toDate();
```

When debug mode is off, if I select 8 or 9 value from the control, its not able to format the value.

When I am in debug mode, and select 8 or 9, its able to format the value as:

```
Fri May 22 2020 09:00:00 GMT-0600 (Mountain Daylight Time)
```

I have seen many threads discussing the same issue but solution provided in them haven not helped me to format this correctly.

I am trying to print arrivalDateTime  value, it shows like this in log ;

```
Date { NaN }
```

I am trying this but it does not work, it days toDate is not a function :

```
moment().format(`YYYY-MM-DD ${arrivalTime}:00:00`).toDate();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Took me a while but I finally figured it out.

[this helped me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35660278/some-code-only-works-while-chrome-debugger-is-active/35728172)

This didn't work:

```
 const arrivalDateTime = moment(
   `${todaysDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD")} ${arrivalTime}:00:00`,
 ).toDate();
```

This worked:

```
const arrivalDateTime = moment(
  `${todaysDate.format('YYYY/MM/DD')} ${arrivalTime}:00`,
).toDate();
```

// note that engine does not seem to like parsing with ' - '. so I changed it to ' / '

still not sure the reason behind it.